# IP router not forward the packets it receives

Tags: ip, packet-path

I have been searching for a answer to this and have not found a definite conclusion. Everything seems to suggest

`In what cases may an IP router not forward the packets it receives?`

My guess which could be right or wrong is if IP destination address is outside of a LAN or if the IP destination address is not in its routing table.

Comment: Unfortunately, all "education, certification, or homework" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there may be rules/policies/ACLs explicitly dropping a packet, a router generally cannot forward a packet when it can't be matched to the routing table, ie. when there is not route toward the destination.